# What is the difference between JASO MB and JASO MA and JASO MA2

Tags: motorcycle, oil

I want to ask the differences between the JASO MA MA2 and MB oils.I have checked the JASO website but does not offer much information on this.Also why is it advised to not use JASO MB oil for motorcycles

Comment: Welcome to the site. Where does it "*advised to not use JASO MB oil for motorcycles*"? Also, if you need to know which oil is used in your bike, please give us some make/model information.

Comment: Basically down to whether the bike has a wet clutch or not...

Comment: @CharlieRB.The Motul Scooter LE oil has a warning note stating `Do not use for geared motorcycles'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [oilspecification.org](http://www.oilspecifications.org/jaso.php), it has to do with friction reducing components.

> JASO introduced the MA and MB specification to distinguish between
>   friction modified and non friction modified engine oils.

For motorcycles which share the oil with the engine, clutch and transmission, it is not a good idea to have advanced friction reduction additives that can cause slip. In those cases use the `MA` type.

Other configurations can use the `MB`, which has the additives to make it the lowest friction rating.

Bottom line, use what the motorcycle manufacturer recommends.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you :
[image]

Sourced from : https://passenger.lubrizoladditives360.com/understanding-jaso-ma-and-mb/

Answer (score 0):

For my vespa 125 cc I used castrol power 1 racing fully synthetic  10w-50 it is suitable for scooters we can put this type of oil for scooters are wat if we use wrong grade whether it will damage engine are wat. It is very high grade oil because in India temperature crosses around 45°cesius normally in summer so scooter oil losses it viscosity in extreme temperature. So I changed my grade to 10w-50 fully synthetic