# Honda Dio performance reduced after 9000km

Tags: honda, performance

I see a drastic performance reduction on my 2017 Honda Dio gearless scooter which has just completed 9000km. I just went back to the service center and the guy there, after riding my scooter said the performance is good. But when I told him to compare it with a brand new scooter, he refused. Is it normal to have a drastic reduction in initial acceleration after running just 9000km? He said that this cannot be fixed without having a drastic hit on the fuel economy.

Initially the vehicle would pickup quite well when just twisting the accelerator knob, by 10%, now I need to twist it by a good 25% to attain the same result. Is it possible it is just the knob that needs recaliberation? If yes, how do I explain this to the mechanic? Most people act like *know-it-all*s and don't really like taking advises from customers.

I would also like to add that somtimes, I get the feeling that it revs too much and does not actually go as expected, as if the clutch is partially engaged and all the revs are being wasted.

Comment: That is usually because the info from the customer is often worse than useless... and that is based on experience. "the noise is from this side" no, fault is on the other side... etc etc.

Comment: I know the feeling. I personally work in the software field. But when I realise the client makes sense I usually pay more attention. It's not that difficult to figure out if someone is *that* dumb. Either way, I would like to learn how things work in the automotive industry.

Comment: Ask the mech to check and adjust the throttle...

Comment: Before I do that, I would like to know if this is something normal that would happen to a scooter after running this many kms. I mean an actual performance reduction which might require engine tuning and stuff which will reduce the fuel economy, like the mechanic said.

Comment: The cables can stretch so yes...especially if the throttle is forced wide open against the stop.

Comment: So now you add a different situation...

Comment: Sorry about that. Just added another observation, but that is not applicable all the time. It's just sometimes that I find this, especially when trying to accelerate out of an overtake manoeuvre.

Answer (score 2):

I understand you are facing issue with the initial pickup of your Honda Dio after just riding it for 9000 kms which is quite strange as Honda engines usually lasts for long time without much fuss.If I were you I would do following as first steps:

1. Check for air filter: If its too dirty replace it.
2. Carburetor: though a 4 stroke engine does not require cleaning of the carburettor too frequently but I would give it a try
3. Drive belt: As you said it revs too much but does not gives power to wheels you can get your drive belt and variator inspected if they need replacement.
4. Engine oil: Most important change it as per recommended schedule and use **proper grade and viscosity of it. i.e 10W30 JASO MB** is the recommended engine oil for most gear less scooters. There are many ignorant people out there who are not aware about difference between an oil made for motorcycle vs scooter.Even Honda authorised service centres would do the mistake.You can try this [engine oil](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/44950/what-is-the-difference-between-jaso-mb-and-jaso-ma-and-jaso-ma2)

   I hope that helps.Also for your knowledge you can read this [difference between bike vs scooter oil](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/44950/what-is-the-difference-between-jaso-mb-and-jaso-ma-and-jaso-ma2)

Comment: At 9000 kms is it still under warranty and will doing this work invalidate it?

Comment: i do not think so if its done at the authorised service centre

Comment: +1 for suggesting air filter, but finally I don't know whether going through all the steps you have mentioned will fix the problems. As the vehicle is still under warranty, the mechanic did clean the air filter, changed oil and corrected the "clutch" mechanism under the free-service scheme that I have.

Comment: Honda Dio is fitted with viscous(paper) type air filter that is not advised to be cleaned but to be replaced if it needs to.Also all the above mentioned steps can be done at the authorised service station on request

Answer (score 1):

You need to explain to the mechanic that there are two things you would like checked :

1) the throttle operation and cable adjustment

2) the operation of the clutch or equivalent (is it auto? If so has the fluid been checked?) if manual then is that adjusted correctly?

Comment: I just got the vehicle back from the service center again and there seems to be a marginal improvement. After asking the mechanic, what he did, he said he cleaned the air filter and adjusted the clutch mechanism which was kind of loose. The vehicle still does not feel as good as when it was new though.